# Why isn't this javascript counter working?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a counter that goes up to 100 in 10 seconds and then loops. What is wrong with my code?

```
window.onload = function () {
    var showPercent = window.setInterval(function () {
        if (currentPercent < 100) {
            currentPercent += 1;
        } else {
            currentPercent = 0;
        }

        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = currentPercent;
    }, 100);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JBVA2/

Comment: First tip: see declaring variables with Javascript's [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

Comment: Second tip: look in the [`console`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Debugging_JavaScript) and you will see `Uncaught ReferenceError: currentPercent is not defined`

Comment: Third tip: Your code doesn't even execute because you are assigning to `window.onload` **after** the page was already loaded (the jsFiddle is set up to run the JavaScript "onLoad").

Comment: Indeed: consider setting `no wrap - in <body>` in your jsFiddle options.

Comment: Fourth tip: In your case it doesn't matter but see [`Security Considerations`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML#Security_considerations) when using `.innerHTML`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not declaring `currentPercent` anywhere on your code, you should add something like: `var currentPercent = 0;` before `showPercent`

<kbd>**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/rojeveto/1/edit)**</kbd>

Comment: Wow, five seconds XD +1

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol you're pretty fast I was just lucky this time :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentPercent = 0;  

setInterval(function() {
    if (currentPercent < 100) {
       currentPercent += 1;
    } else {
       currentPercent = 0;
    }

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = currentPercent;
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle you already had it to run onload. The problem with your snippet is that `currentPercent` needs to exist outside the setInterval callback scope:

```
var currentPercent = 0;
var showPercent = window.setInterval(function() {
  if (currentPercent < 100) {
    ++currentPercent;
  } else {
    currentPercent = 0;
  }

 document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = currentPercent;
}, 100);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JBVA2/4/

Answer (score 0):

I got the following error when loading the page in Firefox with Firebug enabled:

ReferenceError: currentPercent is not defined

You're comparing the value stored in variable currentPercent against '100', but the variable hasn't been defined yet.  Making a couple of small alterations to the code makes it work just fine:

```
  var currentPercent = 0;
  window.onload = function() {
    var showPercent = window.setInterval(function() {
      if (currentPercent < 100) {
        currentPercent += 1;
      }

      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = currentPercent;
    }, 100);
  };
```